# How to work with the Cosmo Raiting Library in table cells? (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I don't understand how to link the selection of a set of rating stars to each cell and save this value?

Cosmo lib: https://github.com/evgenyneu/Cosmos

My Code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCellTableViewCell
    
    
    let currentNameItem = gameNameArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.gameNameLabel?.text = currentNameItem["Name"] as? String
    
    // MARK: - переменная из словаря - если true ставим галочку - если нет убираем
    if (currentNameItem["isCompleted"] as? Bool) == true {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }
    
    let currentSubNameItem = gameSubNameArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.subGameNameLabel?.text = currentSubNameItem["Name"] as? String
    
    let currentScoreItem = gameScoreArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.gameScoreValue?.text = currentScoreItem["Name"] as? String
    
    let currentImageItem = gameImageArray[indexPath.row]
    guard let url = URL(string: currentImageItem["Name"] as! String) else { return cell }
    cell.gameImage.sd_setImage(with: url, completed: nil)
    
    
    //I can set the rating value
    cell.fiveStarRaiting.rating = 5
    let currentRaitingItem = raitingArray[indexPath.row] //array where I would like to save the ratings
    cell.fiveStarRaiting.rating = currentRaitingItem //here, the values from the rating array should be pulled up by the ide
    //allows you to save the rating value at the end of the finger movement gesture
    cell.fiveStarRaiting.didFinishTouchingCosmos = { [self] raiting in raitingArray.append(raitingStarValue)}
    print(raitingArray.count)
    
    
    //cell.testButton0.addTarget(self, action: #selector(testFuncButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You mean, Cosmos Rating?

Answer (score 0):

As you know, table view cells are reusable, so when you scrolls and when cells are disappeared then its values are also cleared that's how table view and collection view works.

So if you want to save those ratings then you can go with a local temporary dictionary.

e.g.

```
var ratingsArray = [Int:Float]()
```

store your indexpath as key in "ratingsArray" dictionary and set its value as cosmos ratings.

and set cosmos ratings values as prefill in "cellForRowAt" table view method,

```
if ratingsArray.keys.contains(indexPath.row) {
    cell.fiveStarRaiting.rating = 5
}
else {
    cell.fiveStarRaiting.rating = 0 // set starts default value here
}

cell.fiveStarRaiting.didFinishTouchingCosmos = { [self] rating in 

    ratingsArray[indexPath.row] = rating

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I don't quite understand the first point. temporary dictionary - I have all dictionaries containing images and texts in a separate file Model. I save the data in them like this: var gameScoreArray: [[String: Any]] {
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "gameScoreSave")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
    get {
        if let array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "gameScoreSave") as? [[String: Any]] {
            return array
        } else {
            return []
        }
    }
}

Comment: How can I make this item: "save your indexpath as a key in the "ratingsArray" dictionary and set its value as cosmos ratings" ?